# How does token based authentication work?

Tags: django, authentication

I implement a web application (with Python+Django - to the extent that matters). Users can log in normally with username and password, but in addition I want to provide an API which users use to script the interaction with my site.

For the API authentication my plan was to do something like this:

1. In the database I create table with 'tokens' - i.e. random strings which point to the user database.
2. The user gets a token string.
3. For every API call the user passes the token string along with their request

In the API implementation the code:

1. Verify the token.
2. Log the correct user in and execute the API function as the user matching the token.
3. Log the user out again.
4. Return the result

Does this make sense? On the one hand it seems very simple - on the other hand it feels quite homemade, something I have heard is not recommended when it comes to security related topics?

Comment: Just use django-rest-framework, it's all supported out of the box my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would wholeheartedly recommend looking at `django-rest-framework`

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/

It literally does all of that and more!

Nope, not a sales person, just a developer :)

It handles quite literally any use case you can think of, and I would be happy to discuss at great length any its not suitable for.

It handles:

- Authentication
- Parsing
- Encoding
- View or object level permissions
- Object serialisation
- Object creation
- Object deletion
- Automatically generated documentation
- Several authentication methods, including custom managed methods
- And a bunch of other stuff that makes writing API's in Django much easier

All in all it supports most if not all use cases.

**EDIT**

It is worth noting that there is a very good reason DRF has short lived access tokens. That is because of security.

Let's say a malicious actor gets hold of your short lived access token, thats a lot better than a "long life" one as you described.

It's worth weighing up security and ease of access, security and protecting your users should always paramount.

Futhermore, I would recommend taking a look at DRF Knox, which is recommended in the authentication section of the DRF docs:

https://github.com/James1345/django-rest-knox

Comment: A real Swiss Army knife;-) Yes - I had looked on DRF and will probably use it. From my initial reading I had the impression that the tokens from DRF were short lived - whereas I want something with 'quite long' lifetime like AWS access tokens. I also do not understand the log out step - i.e. my point three in the second list, or maybe the user is just supposed to remain logged in?

Comment: I would look at customising an authentication class and adding custom authentication  model. But it would need to be discussed as part of a question you have tried already before I can give you context specific information. But you are correct, generally out of the box it's short lived for a goof reason.